# Evaluate exam in moodle with a custom evaluation scheme

Tags: r, r-exams

I'm trying to implement a simple evaluation scheme using `exams`, but none of the options seems to do what I'd like:

**There are 5 answer options. I want to give 0.2 points for all marked correct answers and all unmarked incorrect answers, and zero points for all unmarked good answers and marked incorrect answers.** Therefore, a task can yield 0, .2, .4, .6, .8, or 1 points.

I'm aware that this evaluation scheme may have some shortcomings, but I'm counterbalancing those in other ways.

I was able to implement this when I did scanned exams, because I could use a string distance function to tell how many characters differ in two strings that coded the answers and the solutions. But I want to do this in moodle now, so I cannot control the evaluation.

Here are some examples that I tried:

```
ee <- exams_eval(partial = TRUE, rule = "all", negative = FALSE)
ee$pointsum("01111", "10000") # should be 0 and returns 0
ee$pointsum("01111", "10001") # should be .2 but returns 0
ee$pointsum("11111", "10001") # should be .4 and returns .4
ee$pointsum("00000", "11001") # should be .4 but returns 0
ee$pointsum("11011", "00011") # should be .6 but returns .5
ee$pointsum("11111", "10101") # should be .6 and returns .6
ee$pointsum("11001", "10001") # Should be .8 but returns .66
ee$pointsum("00000", "00001") # should be .8 but returns 0
ee$pointsum("11001", "11001") # Should be 1 and returns 1
ee$pointsum("00000", "00000") # Should be 1 but returns 0
```

The previous examples yield the same result when using `rule = "false"` or `rule = "false2"`, or `rule = "true"`. When using `rule = "none"`, this is the only change:

```
ee$pointsum("01111", "10001") # should be .2 but returns 0.25
```

**Is there a way to implement the above mentioned evaluation scheme in moodle?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R/exams package currently does not support the desired evaluation scheme because Moodle does not support it. Looking at the Moodle docs at https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/Moodle_XML_format#Multiple_choice shows that you can see that partial credit schemes always work in the following way:

- Not marking/clicking an `<answer>` does not yield any points.
- Marking/clicking an answer option yields a certain `fraction` of the overall points.

Hence, R/exams handles this by assigning the fraction 1/#correct to marking/clicking a correct answer. The `rule` argument only controls which fraction is subtracted when marking/clicking an incorrect answer. The default is the `"false2"` rule that essentially subtracts 1/#incorrect. For example, an item with 2 correct and 3 incorrect answers is processed with:

```
ee2 <- exams_eval(partial = TRUE, rule = "false2", negative = FALSE)
ee2$pointvec("11000")
##        pos        neg 
##  0.5000000 -0.3333333
```

When you use `rule = "all"` then 100% of the points are removed if an incorrect answer is marked/clicked:

```
ee <- exams_eval(partial = TRUE, rule = "all", negative = FALSE)
ee$pointvec("11000")
##  pos  neg 
##  0.5 -1.0
```

There are learning management systems that support more flexible ways of computing the points (e.g., in QTI this is in principle possible) but I don't think your particular scheme can be implemented in Moodle. *(If anyone knows more than the Moodle docs above, let me know!)*

*(You said you are aware of the drawbacks of your evaluation scheme - which is, of course, fair enough. However, just for the record in case anybody else reads this: I'm personally not very fond of the scheme you are proposing. Even if on average each answer option is correct with 50% probability, students can obtain 50% of the points on average by either always clicking all of the answer options or by always clicking none of the answer options. This can even get higher if the probability for each options deviates from 50%. Hence, this sets strange incentives for some students...at least the business and economics students I'm typically teaching.)*

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, there is no combination of `exams_eval` parameters that would give the desired scheme. One can verify that by checking all 20 combinations. For instance,

```
combs <- expand.grid(partial = c(TRUE, FALSE), negative = c(TRUE, FALSE),
                     rule = c("false2", "false", "true", "all", "none"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
sapply(1:nrow(combs), function(n) {
  ee <- exams_eval(partial = combs[n, 1], negative = combs[n, 2], rule = combs[n, 3])
  ee$pointsum("11001", "10001")
})
#  [1]  0.6666667 -1.0000000  0.6666667  0.0000000  0.6666667 -1.0000000  0.6666667  0.0000000
#  [9]  0.6666667 -1.0000000  0.6666667  0.0000000  0.6666667 -1.0000000  0.6666667  0.0000000
# [17]  0.6666667 -1.0000000  0.6666667  0.0000000
```

---

That's particularly strange because the scheme is quite simple - counting matches, which we may implement as follows:

```
pointsum <- function(correct, answer) {
  correct <- as.numeric(strsplit(correct, "")[[1]])
  answer <- as.numeric(strsplit(answer, "")[[1]])
  mean(correct == answer)
}

pointsum("01111", "10000") # should be 0
# [1] 0
pointsum("01111", "10001") # should be .2
# [1] 0.2
pointsum("11111", "10001") # should be .4
# [1] 0.4
pointsum("00000", "11001") # should be .4
# [1] 0.4
pointsum("11011", "00011") # should be .6
# [1] 0.6
pointsum("11111", "10101") # should be .6
# [1] 0.6
pointsum("11001", "10001") # should be .8
# [1] 0.8
pointsum("00000", "00001") # should be .8
# [1] 0.8
pointsum("11001", "11001") # should be 1
# [1] 1
pointsum("00000", "00000") # should be 1
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I understand that there is no way currently to implement this scheme in moodle.

Comment: @TamasNagy, dealing with moddle itself is no longer about programming, at least without additional details. I suggest to update your question with the details on what moodle is capable of in terms of R.

Comment: You are right, so I wrote a script that changes the point values of the answers in the exported moodle xml file, but I have not yet been able to figure out how the values should be changed.

Comment: @TamasNagy, I'm not really following. If your new issue relates enough to the original question, you could update it with an explanation. Otherwise (and if it *is* a question) I'm afraid you are going to need to post a new one.

Comment: @JuliusVenoira The question is still the same: if and how I can implement this particular grading scheme in a moodle exam. The best solution would be through the `exams` package but I'm open to other ideas, I already know how do this when I have control over the evaluation, but I could not find a way to extend this to moodle.

Comment: @TamasNagy, the initial question of how to implement the specified scheme with `exams` (so that, as a result, you could use it on moodle) is fine and is answered since we agreed that it's not possible to be done. The question "How to get this scheme working on moodle" no longer seems to be necessarily about R, primarily is about moodle, the role of programming is unclear. As such, I believe such this question would be closed as too broad/off topic as "asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"/off topic as not about programming.